# what is the difference between SOAP web request and HTTPWebRequset?

Tags: web-services, soap

I have a client who is a service provider of hotels I sent it a request for hotels using soap then I didn't get any response but as I sent it using HTTPWebrequest It worked fine but I didn't understand the difference between SOAP and HTTPWebrequest can anyone post I am new at this 
thanks

Comment: It is explained quite well here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792524/soap-versus-http

Comment: possible duplicate of [Main differences between SOAP and RESTful web services in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131965/main-differences-between-soap-and-restful-web-services-in-java)